# Send to public group, not send myself

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

How to send message to Public Group contain my bot already (using your C# code)?

```
//below only send to myself

Interaction.InputBox("Type some text to send to ourselves\n(Saved Messages)", "Send to self");
```

Comment: what is this? is this even related to WTelegramClient? `InputBox` seems like a UI control rather than a function in telegram bot/client API, please provide more detail and clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Read the [README](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/) and follow its tutorial.

It demonstrate how to send a message in a group you're in.

Note: this library is for controlling user account, it is not recommended for bot account. You should use [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) instead